# How to change max file descriptors for a process?

Tags: 16.04, elasticsearch

While running elasticsearch as a service i get the following error :

```
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
```

But the error doesn't seem to occur when I run the elasticsearch directly using its file.

I have already updated the limits.conf file.
I have used ulimit command to check the limit and it gives 200000.
I have also updated the /etc/pam.d/su file

But I still seem to get this error

Comment: yes but did you run that command A.) as root and B.) while elastic search was shut down? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html

Comment: Yes, I have done that and I am still facing the same error.